# Converting Byte Literal to Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data that looks like this:

In bytes literal form

```
data

b'[{"Name":"USA Stocks","Code":"US","OperatingMIC":"XNAS, XNYS","Country":"USA","Currency":"USD","CountryISO2":"US","CountryISO3":"USA"},{"Name":"London Exchange","Code":"LSE","OperatingMIC":"XLON","Country":"UK","Currency":"GBP","CountryISO2":"GB","CountryISO3":"GBR"}]'
```

I coverted

```
data_decode = data.decode("utf-8")
```

I am trying to get a pandas data frame from this.

```
df = pd.DataFrame((data_decode))
```

> ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!

```
df = pd.DataFrame(eval(data_decode))
```

> NameError: name 'null' is not defined

Comment: @cottontail FYI: `FutureWarning: Passing literal json to 'read_json' is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. To read from a literal string, wrap it in a 'StringIO' object.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Feed the byte string to `pandas.read_json()`, which supports a file-like object.  `io.BytesIO(data)` wraps the data in a file-like object.  No need to decode the bytes unless the JSON data is in a non-UTF8 encoding.  If it is decode with that encoding and use `io.StringIO` instead.

```py
import pandas as pd
from io import BytesIO

data = b'[{"Name":"USA Stocks","Code":"US","OperatingMIC":"XNAS, XNYS","Country":"USA","Currency":"USD","CountryISO2":"US","CountryISO3":"USA"},{"Name":"London Exchange","Code":"LSE","OperatingMIC":"XLON","Country":"UK","Currency":"GBP","CountryISO2":"GB","CountryISO3":"GBR"}]'
df = pd.read_json(BytesIO(data))
print(df)
```

Output:

```
              Name Code OperatingMIC Country Currency CountryISO2 CountryISO3
0       USA Stocks   US   XNAS, XNYS     USA      USD          US         USA
1  London Exchange  LSE         XLON      UK      GBP          GB         GBR
```

Note: If you received this data via a web API via the `requests` module, just use the `.json()` method of the response.